# How to load a csv where some lines in one column contain extra "," separators? Getting "Error tokenizing data"

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to load a csv (reviews from Google Play Console) using pandas, where columns are separated by ',' (comma). However some of the writings reviews include commas within the text and obviously shouldn't be split by them. In these cases the reviews are originally contained in a quotation mark, like this:

```
App_rating,Date,Review,App_version
5,2020-03-01,Great app,3.0.0
2,2020-03-02,"Lame, previous version was better",4.0.0
4,2020-03-01,Good,3.0.1
```

I tried with this code:

```py
input_fd = open('reviews.csv', encoding='utf8', errors = 'backslashreplace')
pd.read_csv(input_fd, sep=',')
```

But getting error like:
`Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 4 fields in line 2, saw 5`

I don't want to use `error_bad_lines=False` as I need to keep all the lines.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `open` the file to read it inside `pandas`.

Just use :

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename)  ## filename is the complete path of your csv
```

No need to specify separator here.

I read your csv like this:

```
cat t1.txt

App_rating,Date,Review,App_version
5,2020-03-01,Great app,3.0.0
2,2020-03-02,"Lame, previous version was better",4.0.0
4,2020-03-01,Good,3.0.1

In [1745]: df = pd.read_csv('t1.txt')                                                                                                                                                         

In [1746]: df                                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[1746]: 
   App_rating        Date                             Review App_version
0           5  2020-03-01                          Great app       3.0.0
1           2  2020-03-02  Lame, previous version was better       4.0.0
2           4  2020-03-01                               Good       3.0.1
```

Comment: I might have missed something in this dummy example. My original data is in Cyrillic alphabet and contains emojis. Does this change anything?

Comment: @prozumek No it should not change anything. Try and run it and let me know if you face issues. If possible, share those rows which could have issues.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try to use the `delimiter` argument in the read function?

"quotecharstr (length 1), optional

The character used to denote the start and end of a quoted item. Quoted items can include the delimiter and it will be ignored."
`quotecharstr("\"") or something similar`